# Convert NSSound to AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, macos, audio, avaudioplayer, nssound

I have some `NSSound` objects that I'd like to convert to `AVAudioPlayer` instances. I have file paths (`NSURL`s) associated with the `NSSound` objects, but the original file may not exist. Here is what I have so far:

```
class SoundObj: NSObject {
    var path: NSURL?
    var sound: NSSound?
    var player: AVAudioPlayer
}

let aSound = SoundObj()
aSound.path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///path/to/sound.m4a")
aSound.sound = NSSound(contentsOfURL: aSound.path)!

do {
    try aSound.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: aSound.path)
} catch {
    // perhaps use AVAudioPlayer(data: ...)?
}
```

How do I convert an `NSSound` object to an `AVAudioPlayer` instance?

Comment: If the audio file doesn't exist won't this line crash? `aSound.sound = NSSound(contentsOfURL: aSound.path)!`

Comment: Yes, but for this case `.sound` is never null.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you can get sound data from a NSSound.

Comment: @brimstone is there a way to verify that?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Would you like a custom `AVAudioPlayer` initializer that takes in an `NSSound` and returns a `AVAudioPlayer`?  I'm thinking `AVAsset` might be better for your needs.

Comment: @JAL yes, that would work.

Comment: Hey Matt did my answer help you?  Feel free to follow up if you have any other questions.

Comment: @JAL yes it did. Is there any way you know of to get NSData from an NSSound? That's the only other thing that I would be looking for.

Comment: I unfortunately do not see anything about data in the private header.  You might have some luck by adding `var data: NSData? { get }` ( or `_data`) to the protocol and trying to access it that way, but I doubt that will work.  I will investigate further when I get back to my Mac tomorrow morning.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I could not find any way to access any `NSData`objects from an `NSSound`.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.  The data representation must be hidden somewhere in the implementation of the class.  I did my best to try and win the bounty :)  Let me know if you chose to award it or have any other questions.

Comment: @JAL Do you think it would be possible to write the `NSSound` object to a temporary file, and then use `NSData(contentsOfFile: String)` to get the data to use to initialize the `AVAudioPlayer` object?

Comment: @Matt sure, `NSSound` conforms to `NSCoding` so you could write the data to a file using `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I didn't see a public interface to get the URL from an `NSSound` object, so I went digging through the [private headers](https://github.com/mstg/OSX-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/AppKit/NSSound.h) to see what I could find.  Turns out there are private instance method `url` and `_url` which return the URL of an `NSSound`.  Presumably these are getters for an `NSURL` ivar or property.

With Objective-C this would be easy: we would just add the methods to a new  interface or extension.  With pure Swift things are a little trickier, and we need to expose the accessor via an Objective-C protocol:

```
@objc protocol NSSoundPrivate {
    var url: NSURL? { get }
}
```

Since `url` is an instance method, you may get better results with `func url() -> NSURL?` instead of using a variable.  Your milage may vary: using a `var` to emulate the behavior of a read-only property seemed to work for me.

I wrote a new convenience initializer in an extension on `AVAudioPlayer`:

```
extension AVAudioPlayer {
    convenience init?(sound: NSSound) throws {    
        let privateSound = unsafeBitCast(sound, NSSoundPrivate.self)    
        guard let url = privateSound.url else { return nil }
        do {
            try self.init(contentsOfURL: url)
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let url = NSURL(...)    
if let sound = NSSound(contentsOfURL: url, byReference: true) {
    do {
        let player = try AVAudioPlayer(sound: sound)
        player?.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }        
}
```

After attempting to find anything related to `NSData` in the ivars, instance methods, and properties of an NSSound, I have come to the conclusion that the data portion of whatever you use to initialize an `NSSound` is obfuscated somewhere in the implementation of the class, and is not available like the URL is.